# grep on two strings

Tags: r, regex

I'm working to grab two different elements in a string.

The string look like this,

```
str <- c('a_abc', 'b_abc', 'abc', 'z_zxy', 'x_zxy', 'zxy')
```

I have tried with the different options in `?grep`, but I can't get it right, 'm doing something like this,

```
grep('[_abc]:[_zxy]',str, value = TRUE)
```

and what I would like is,

```
[1] "a_abc" "b_abc" "z_zxy" "x_zxy"
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use normal parentheses `(`, not the square brackets `[`

```
grep('_(abc|zxy)',str, value = TRUE)
[1] "a_abc" "b_abc" "z_zxy" "x_zxy"
```

To make the `grep` a bit more flexible, you could do something like:

```
grep('_.{3}$',str, value = TRUE)
```

Which will match an underscore `_`  followed by any character `.` three times `{3}` followed immediately by the end of the string `$`

Comment: Thanks, I really like your response.

Answer (score 6):

this should work: `grep('_abc|_zxy', str, value=T)`

`X|Y` matches when either `X` matches or `Y` matches

Answer (score 1):

In this case just doing:

```
str[grep("_",str)]
```

will work... is it more complicated in your specific case?

Comment: It is a bit more complicated in my case, I should have shown that in my question. Thanks for your concise answer though.

Comment: No problem, looks like it's sorted now